# Python 2.7 print strings

Tags: python

I want to print all names with the example below. Names are random every time.

```
txt = "[something name=\"Paul\" other=\"1/1/1\"][something name=\"James\" other=\"4/3/5\"][something name=\"Victor\" other=\"7/2/6\"][something name=\"Jane\" other=\"4/3/6\"]"
```

I know how to print first of this names:

```
print str(txt[txt.index('[something name=\"')+17:txt.index(' other')-1])
```

but how can I print all? I need to print all names in new line:

```
Paul
James
Victor
Jane
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you can use regex here:

```
import re
txt = "[something name=\"Paul\" other=\"1/1/1\"][something name=\"James\" other=\"4/3/5\"][something name=\"Victor\" other=\"7/2/6\"][something name=\"Jane\" other=\"4/3/6\"]"
for name in re.findall('name\=\\"(.*?)\\\"', txt):
    print name
```

Prints:

```
Paul
James
Victor
Jane
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to split the string as follows:

```
txt = "[something name=\"Paul\" other=\"1/1/1\"][something name=\"James\" other=\"4/3/5\"][something name=\"Victor\" other=\"7/2/6\"][something name=\"Jane\" other=\"4/3/6\"]"

for x in txt.split(']'):
    if len(x):
        print x.split('"', 2)[1]
```

Giving:

```
Paul
James
Victor
Jane
```